# ActiveMQ 5.17.4 network bridges as consumers

Tags: activemq-classic

Hi I have a activemq over a network working as master slave(4 pairs)

But for some reason the messages placed in one queue(in host-4) doesn't show a bridge to host-1
**ActiveMQ Brokers**

*Master-slave*

akl1-mmh1

akl2-mmh2

akl3-mmh3

akl4-mmh4

When i look at a queue this is what i'm seeing as consumers in AKL1
[image: AKL1]

Whereas AKL2 and akl3 has duplicate network bridge as highlighted
[image]

AKL4 is with exact consumer(application)

Couple of question with respect to above pictures

1. Is it expected to have network bridges as consumers in each broker/queue
2. why does it have duplicate bridges? Not sure where to start to identify the issues

Sample network configuration in AKL2, similar to below config akl1 will have bridge to (node2/3/4) and akl2 will have node1,3,4

```
<networkConnector name="network_node3"
                          userName="xxxxxxxxxx"
                          password="xxxxxxxxxx"
                          uri="masterslave:(ssl://amq-uat-mmh3:61617,ssl://amq-uat-akl3:61617)"
                          networkTTL="3"
                          conduitSubscriptions="true"
                          decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                          suppressDuplicateQueueSubscriptions="true"
                          duplex="false"/>
```

Comment: I did verify for any network/firewall issues and i cannot find any. Also performed a restart multiple times. After the restart it works fine for some time(probably 2 days) but then the issue starts appearing again.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to separate networkTTL out into two separate parameters:

1. consumerTTL=1
2. messageTTL=4

This approach is easier to reason the desired behavior of the network of brokers.

Note: @Born78's response to use 'failover:' is incorrect and conflicts with 'masterslave'. Network Connectors reconnect by default.

Comment: I did not test the masterslave configuration with failover, but in our cluster setup (network connector with static url), I had to configure failover (<networkConnector uri="static:failover...) - without that, the bridge did not survive network interruptions

Comment: @Born78 what version of ActiveMQ?

Comment: we have 5.16.3 in use

Comment: @MattPavlovich Thanks for the above suggestion when we have with the above configuration the activemq nodes are behaving properly, but when a network issue occurs queue is going with 0 consumers and never establishes a bridge again with other nodes. To resolve we need to delete the queue again and let it create a queue again to establish a bridge.

Answer (score -1):

> After the restart it works fine for some time(probably 2 days)

I seems like you have network interruptions, so you have to configure [failover transport](https://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) to deal with that:

```
masterslave:(failover:(ssl://amq-uat-mmh3:61617)?initialReconnectDelay=100,failover:(ssl://amq-uat-akl3:61617)?initialReconnectDelay=100)
```